# How to get consistent execution times in Docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-engine

I am using Docker to isolate a specific process. This process is run repeatedly a number of times on a multi-core virtual machine.

Each execution time is measured by its wall clock time and recorded. I'm looking to get time differences smaller than 200 ms. Unfortunately, I get about 1 second difference between the best and worst executions in Docker. I don't understand why. I want to bring it down to < 200 ms.

Here is a chart to illustrate my problem:
[image]

Here the blue columns represent the native time executions in ms, which are pretty consistent, while the orange columns show the execution times when the same code is run as a Docker process.

My goals is to get consistent execution times in Docker.

Here is my minimal reproducible example:

`mem.cpp` This program performs memory expensive operations to take time.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
string CustomString(int len)
{
    string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i<len; i++)
        result = result + 'm';

    return result;
}
int main()
{
   int len = 320;
   std::vector< string > arr;
   for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
       string s = CustomString(len);
       arr.push_back(s);
   }
   cout<<arr[10] <<"\n";
   return 0;
}
```

`script.sh` This script is the starting point for the Docker containers and it compiles and runs the above C++ program and records its wall time.

```
#!/bin/bash

# compile the file
g++ -O2 -std=c++17 -Wall -o _sol mem.cpp

# execute file and record execution time (wall clock)
ts=$(date +%s%N)
./_sol
echo $((($(date +%s%N) - $ts)/1000000)) ms
```

python program. It uses `ProcessPoolExecutor` for parallelism. It copies the files into the Docker containers and executes `script.sh`.

```
import docker
import logging
import os
import tarfile
import tempfile
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

log_format = '%(asctime)s %(threadName)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
dkr = docker.from_env()

def task():
    ctr = dkr.containers.create("gcc:12-bullseye", command="/home/script.sh", working_dir="/home")
    # copy files into container
    cp_to_container(ctr, "./mem.cpp", "/home/mem.cpp")
    cp_to_container(ctr, "./script.sh", "/home/script.sh")
    # run container and capture logs
    ctr.start()
    ec = ctr.wait()
    logs = ctr.logs().decode()
    ctr.stop()
    ctr.remove()
    # handle error
    if (code := ec['StatusCode']) != 0:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred during execution with exit code {code}")
    logging.info(logs)

def file_to_tar(src: str, fname: str):
    f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    abs_src = os.path.abspath(src)
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=f, mode='w') as tar:
        tar.add(abs_src, arcname=fname, recursive=False)
    f.seek(0)
    return f

def cp_to_container(ctr, src: str, dst: str):
    (dir, fname) = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(dst))
    with file_to_tar(src, fname) as tar:
        ctr.put_archive(dir, tar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # set logging level
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=log_format)
    # start ProcessPoolExecutor
    ppex = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=max(os.cpu_count()-1,1))
    for _ in range(21):
        ppex.submit(task)
```

I have tried to use much fewer of the available CPU cores (4 or less out of 8) to make sure that the OS can utilize 4 or more for its own purposes, but that doesn't help. This makes me think the reason lies within Docker Engine most likely.

**EDIT:**

I tried using the newly released `gcc:13-bookworm` image and it performs better than native and much better than `gcc:12-bullseye`. Also, the times are a lot more consistent. This makes me think it has to do something with the image?

[image]

Comment: Note that the startup overhead for a docker container and a process are *not* the same. For example, on my computer, it is 200x faster to run `/bin/true` than to run `docker run -i ubuntu /bin/true`. The shorter the program, the more pronounced this will be.

Comment: What is the underlying operating system? Clearly, Windows and MacOS will have a slight overhead, due to Docker executing inside a virtualized environment.

Comment: @theUndying I measured these times on Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS with Docker Engine - Community 24.0.3

Comment: @StefanZhelyazkov: Your Ubuntu Server was running bare metal or also in a VM? I think you need to profile with e.g. perf to see where CPU is spent.

Comment: The issue is with your ram allocation try to allocate more ram to docker